# Pandas dataframe with or without `open()`

Tags: python, pandas

As well as I know, I thought that there is no difference between reading dataframe with or without `open()`

for example,

```
path = r'Path/to/data.csv'

df = pandas.read_csv(path)
```

and

```
with open(path) as file:
   df = pandas.read_csv(file)
```

should behave the same.

This assumption was right for most of the case I experienced. However, for some csv files, the first case (opening without `open()`) is raising encoding error, and the latter (opening with `open()`) does not. Both used `encoding='utf16'` as an argument, and the file is `ucs-2-le` encoded.

Can somebody explain the differences?

#### some infos.

OS: Windows10

python = 3.6.9

pandas = 0.25.0

Here's full error stack message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c18edf68a287> in <module>
----> 1 bbc = pd.read_csv(wd / 'ETC_FROM2017.csv', encoding='utf16')

~\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    683         )
    684 
--> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    686 
    687     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    455 
    456     # Create the parser.
--> 457     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    458 
    459     if chunksize or iterator:

~\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

~\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1133     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1134         if engine == "c":
-> 1135             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1136         else:
   1137             if engine == "python":

~\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1904         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1905 
-> 1906         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1907         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1908 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x22 in position 2: truncated data
```

Comment: Please provide the error message you're getting when creating dataframe without `open()`. Normally you shouldn't need to open a file to create a dataframe.

Comment: No idea why the difference in two calls, but note that `ucs-2-le` is _not_ `utf16` if it uses any characters beyond the proper `ucs-2` (like JavaScript does), and it is very possible to get an encoding error when reading `ucs-2-le` files as if they were `utf16` (for the same reason you might get encoding errors when reading `ascii` files as if they were `utf8`).

Comment: @Amadan then how is it explained that the file reads okay with `open()` ?

Comment: I have no idea. I have not addressed your problem at all, just the general idea of `ucs2` and `utf16` being the same thing in the real world. You have not provided a [example] of data, nor even the exact error message asked by the first comment, any answer would be a guess.

Comment: @pavel i've added the full error message

Comment: @Amadan sorry, just added the error message.

Comment: @doyouknowkimchi Check my answer